# Conditional aggregation of VBAK/VBAP fields into single row in infoset

Tags: abap, opensql, sap-query

I encounter the following problem.

---

### What I want to do

I want to create an infoset that would regroup, for a given Purchase Order, data from the `VBAK` table with several lines from the `VBPA` table that should be dispatched to different fields.

[image: Tables join]

Example : for the following PO 111005229 I would like to retrieve in a first field the `KUNNR` field for which `PARVW = 'ER'` and in a second field the `ADRNR` field for which `PARVW = 'BP'`.

Desired output :

[image]

---

### What I've tried

#### Joining both tables in SQ02

I tried to declare the 2 tables `VBAK` and `VBAP` while running the SQ02 TCode and select the desired fields :
[image]

This doesn't work :

- just like in SE16N, the query returns every line of a purchase order when a single line with filtered data is wanted ;
- when using the `CHECK VBPA-PARVW = 'ER'.` in the `Record processing` code part hoping that this would shrink the number of lines to 1 for a given PO, no value at all is returned.

#### Declaring only VBAK table in SQ02

I also tried to declare only the `VBAK` table in SQ02, create the additional field `PERNR_ER` that I want and proceed to join `VBAK` with `VBPA` with `openSQL` code related to these specific fields.

I created the additional fields `PARVW_ER` and `PERNR_ER` with the following code embedded :

```
SELECT PARVW
    INTO PARVW_ER
    FROM VBPA
    WHERE VBELN = VBPA~VBELN.
    AND PARVW = 'ER'.
ENDSELECT.

SELECT PERNR
    INTO PERNR_ER
    FROM VBPA
    WHERE VBELN = VBPA~VBELN.
    AND PARVW = 'ER'.
ENDSELECT.
```

which gives as an output

[image]

I also tried

```
TYPES: begin of TY_TABLE,
    PARVW LIKE VBPA-PARVW,
    PERNR LIKE VBPA-PERNR,
    END OF TY_TABLE.

DATA: WA_TABLE TYPE TY_TABLE,
      IT_TABLE  TYPE TABLE OF TY_TABLE.

SELECT PARVW PERNR
    APPENDING CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE IT_TABLE
    FROM VBPA
    WHERE VBELN = VBPA~VBELN.

LOOP AT IT_TABLE INTO WA_TABLE.
  IF WA_TABLE-PARVW = 'ER'.
    PARVW_ER = WA_TABLE-PARVW.
    PERNR_ER = WA_TABLE-PERNR.
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```

but it returned the same.

---

How should I proceed to get the expected result?

Comment: I think you are not aware of conversions between external and internal format. For PARVW, if you are connected with English language, when you see `ER`, it means the internal value `ZM` (cf table TPAUM).

Answer (score 1):

Use an `INNER JOIN` on the same table and then filter out the unnecessary rows by `PARVW`.

```
REPORT YYY.

TABLES: vbpa.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  vbpa = VALUE #( vbeln = '111005229' parvw = 'SP' kunnr = '100007760' adrnr = '9000002718' ).
  INSERT vbpa.
  vbpa = VALUE #( vbeln = '111005229' parvw = 'BP' kunnr = '100007760' adrnr = '38110' ).
  INSERT vbpa.
  vbpa = VALUE #( vbeln = '111005229' parvw = 'PY' kunnr = '100007760' adrnr = '38110' ).
  INSERT vbpa.
  vbpa = VALUE #( vbeln = '111005229' parvw = 'SH' kunnr = '100007760' adrnr = '38110' ).
  INSERT vbpa.
  vbpa = VALUE #( vbeln = '111005229' parvw = 'ER' pernr = '8071' ).
  INSERT vbpa.

  SELECT t1~vbeln, t2~pernr AS field1, t1~adrnr AS field2
    FROM vbpa AS t1
    INNER JOIN vbpa AS t2
    ON t1~vbeln = t2~vbeln
    INTO TABLE @DATA(l_tab_vbpa)
      WHERE t1~parvw = 'BP'
        AND t2~parvw = 'ER'.

  LOOP AT l_tab_vbpa ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<str_vbpa>).
    WRITE: / <str_vbpa>-vbeln, <str_vbpa>-field1, <str_vbpa>-field2.
  ENDLOOP.

  ROLLBACK WORK.
```

Result

> Test
>
> 111005229  00008071 38110

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this via this simple double `FOR` loop:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_res,
         vbeln  TYPE vbeln,
         field1 TYPE vbpa-pernr,
         field2 TYPE vbpa-adrnr,
       END OF ty_res,
       tt_res TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_res WITH EMPTY KEY.

DATA(lt_vbpa) = VALUE tab_vbpa( ).

APPEND VALUE #( vbeln = '111005229' parvw = 'SP' kunnr = '100007760' adrnr = '9000002718' ) TO lt_vbpa.
APPEND VALUE #( vbeln = '111005229' parvw = 'BP' kunnr = '100007760' adrnr = '38110' ) TO lt_vbpa.
APPEND VALUE #( vbeln = '111005229' parvw = 'PY' kunnr = '100007760' adrnr = '38110' ) TO lt_vbpa.
APPEND VALUE #( vbeln = '111005229' parvw = 'SH' kunnr = '100007760' adrnr = '38110' ) TO lt_vbpa.
APPEND VALUE #( vbeln = '111005229' parvw = 'ER' pernr = '8071' ) TO lt_vbpa.

DATA(result) = VALUE tt_res( FOR ls_vbpa_bp IN lt_vbpa WHERE ( parvw = 'BP' )
                             FOR ls_vbpa_er IN lt_vbpa WHERE ( parvw = 'ER' )
( vbeln  = ls_vbpa_bp-vbeln
  field1 = ls_vbpa_er-pernr
  field2 = ls_vbpa_bp-adrnr ) ).
```

`result` itab contains your desired output.

However, this will work only in this special case where you have only **one** line with `BP` function and **one** with `ER` partner function, which are attached with proper `PERNR/ADRNR` values. In other cases you will need grouping.

Comment: Nice complex solution for a very simple problem!

Comment: Not more complex than yours :)

Comment: Let's agree to disagree. :) Mine is in fact just a simple SQL. :)

Answer (score 1):

This tip from @SandraRossi comment helped me :

> I think you are not aware of conversions between external and internal
>   format. For PARVW, if you are connected with English language, when
>   you see ER, it means the internal value ZM (cf table TPAUM).

I did not know that even with transaction code `SE16N`, fields could display converted data, i.e. it displayed `ER` in my language.

So the solution was to simply filter on `ZM` :

```
SELECT PERNR
    INTO PERNR_ER
    FROM VBPA
    WHERE VBPA~VBELN = VBAK-VBELN AND PARVW = 'ZM'.
ENDSELECT.
```

Comment: Answer edited according to the robot instructions. Please "accept" your answer.